# Reading values from Pandas dataframe rows into equations and entering result back into dataframe

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe. For each row of the dataframe: I need to read values from two column indexes, pass these values to a set of equations, enter the result of each equation into its own column index in the same row, go to the next row and repeat.

After reading the responses to similar questions I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.read_csv("...")

Equation_1 = f(x, y)
Equation_2 = g(x, y)

for index, row in DF.iterrows():
    a = DF[m]
    b = DF[n]

    DF[p] = Equation_1(a, b)
    DF[q] = Equation_2(a, b)
```

Rather than iterating over DF, reading and entering new values for each row, this codes iterates over DF and enters the same values for each row. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Also, from what I have read it is actually faster to treat the DF as a NumPy array and perform the calculation over the entire array at once rather than iterating. Not sure how I would go about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# If your equations are simple enough, do operations column-wise in Pandas:

import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
test # Default column names are 0, 1
test[0] # This is column 0 
test.icol(0) # This is COLUMN 0-indexed, returned as a Series 
test.columns=(['S','Q']) # Column names are easier to use
test #Column names! Use them column-wise:
test['result'] = test.S**2 + test.Q
test # results stored in DataFrame

# For more complicated stuff, try apply, as in Python pandas apply on more columns :

def toyfun(df):
    return df[0]-df[1]**2


test['out2']=test[['S','Q']].apply(toyfun, axis=1)

# You can also define the column names when you generate the DataFrame:
test2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],columns = (list('AB')))
```

Comment: Oh, I should have entered the rest of the code. I am using Pandas. My dataframe is from a read_csv. The equations are just examples.

Comment: Eh, any sample data -- but do columnwise operations as above work for you, or do you need more complicated equations?

Comment: Sorry, my browser was not displaying the page correctly and I could not post. 

To be honest, I do not understand the syntax you are using. It looks like you are referencing columns by column name. There are no names for my columns, they are simply the default numbered index. That is one of the issues I have; Pandas documentation provides few examples that are applicable here in default index notation. They typically give examples with named indexes.

Comment: In the examples you have provided, are these operations being applied to each row in the array, or only a single row?

Comment: (1) I was hoping you could just copy the code and noodle around with it -- does it run in your browser?  
(2) I altered the code to show adding column names; I find it makes the code easier to read; and 
(3) Yes, the operations appy row-wise and the result is stored in a new column of the dataframe. (It doesn't have to be, you can keep the result as a Series, which is vectorish.

Comment: Okay. Answer much edited so you should be able to paste the whole thing straight into an editor an noodle with it. Which you should always do! no better way to learn.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the browser is now working. I will work with this.

Comment: I have attempted this and it actually gives the same result as the code I wrote in my first post. It is calculating a single value for each column. It is not calculating a different value for each column/row index.
This would be so simple to write procedurally that I can't believe there isn't a Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Passing Series as arguments is better, but I'm taken aback by your getting "a single value for each column" in this example, because I definitely don't: at the end of the script the DataFrame `test` has four columns, `S,Q,result,out2`, and the last two were calculated directly from the first two columns. What do you get? A syntax error?

Comment: No, the code runs but places the same value in every row of the two columns. It must record the first or last result and insert it into each row. 

There are hundreds of rows of data.

Comment: Oh! You're talking about the effect this approach has on *your* data? But this tiny sample script does calculate the right values for each row? Can you post a line or two of your data or faked-up data?

Comment: Yes. It may very well calculate the correct result but only one of those results is placed in every row. So, with your example, both the 'result' and 'out2' columns contain a single value for all their rows. 

e.g.,

S     Q     result     out2

Comment: ... Can't see the values you got. At the end of the script, my `test` has different values in each row: `   S  Q  result  out2\n0  1  2       3    -3\n1  3  4      13   -13\n2  5  6      31   -31` (those are values row-wise). No?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this is extremely easy. All that must be done is to define two variables and assign the desired columns to them. Then set "the row to be replaced" equivalent to the equation containing the variables.

Pandas already knows that it must apply the equation to every row and return each value to its proper index. I didn't realize it would be this easy and was looking for more explicit code.

e.g.,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("...") # df is a large 2D array

A = df[0]
B = df[1]

f(A,B) = ....

df[3] = f(A,B)
```

Comment: Is `df` here an array, or a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame? If the latter, you  don't even need intermediate variables A and B: you can pass the Series elements of `df` directly to the function f.

Comment: Its a DataFrame. That could be a possibility; I'll see if I can set it up that way. The problem is that these equations are very long with nearly every permutation of A*B up to the 5th power and there are six of these equations.

Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I guess I could set them up as a function definition.

Comment: I'd set them up as a defined functions just to write test cases for them, personally.